# Error: Metadata version mismatch found version 4, expected 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting an error - Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /root/manappurammob/node_modules/ionic2-date-picker/src-inlined/date-picker.interface.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, when I execute
`ionic cordova build browser --prod`
Without the --prod option, it works. But I would like to have aot enabled for better performance. My package.sjon is

```
{
"name": "paymetry-mobileweb",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-clipboard": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "ion2-calendar": "^2.2.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-date-picker": "^1.1.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^1.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "ionic": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.8",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-clipboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "browser"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: have a look here - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-metadata-version-mismatch-for-module-mobile-node-modules-ionic-native-core-decorators-d-ts-found-version-4-expected-3/145041/2
and - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2107

Comment: Adding the --prod flag to package.json does make the error go away. But it is not actually building for prod. The output has entries like "build dev started", which means it is building in dev mode